# Why does python floor division operator behave like this?

Tags: python

why does python floor division operator behaves like this?
I came across this code snippet and result was quite surprising.

```
a = 1 // 10 
b = -1 // 10
print a,b
a= 0
b=-1
```

printing output obtained results are `a=0` and `b= -1`.

why does `a=0` and `b= -1`?

`//` does floor division, so it's always rounding down?

Comment: Yes, the "floor" means "down".

Comment: In my country, the floors are down and the ceilings are up; we find this more convenient than other arrangements. ;)

Comment: It's straight out of standard mathematics:  The floor operator rounds down to the next integer.  So floor(3.9) equals floor(3.1) equals 3, and floor(-3.9) equals floor(-3.1) equals -4.  You will find this definition throughout computer languages and libraries.

Comment: On a more serious note, it's very handy that Python's integer division is floor division. For example, here's a demo of finding the greatest multiple of 5 ≤ a given number: `[(i, i//5*5) for i in range(-10, 11)]`. If `//` rounded towards zero instead of towards negative infinity that wouldn't work properly for negative numbers. And we can also use `//` to perform _ceiling_ division. So this list comp finds the smallest multiple of 5 ≥ a given number: `[(i, i//-5*-5) for i in range(-10, 11)]`

Comment: On a related note, this behaviour is consistent with the fact that in `r = a % b` the sign of `r` is always the same as the sign of `b` because if `q, r = a // b, a % b` then we want `a == q * b + r` to be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`//` in Python is a "floor division" operator. That means that the result of such division is the floor of the result of regular division (performed with / operator).

The floor of the given number is the biggest integer smaller than the this number. For example

`7 / 2 = 3.5` so `7 // 2 = floor of 3.5 = 3`.

For negative numbers it is less intuitive: `-7 / 2 = -3.5`, `so -7 // 2 = floor of -3.5 = -4`. Similarly `-1 // 10 = floor of -0.1 = -1`.

`//` is defined to do the same thing as `math.floor()`: return the largest integer value less than or equal to the floating-point result. **Zero is not less than or equal to -0.1.**

Answer (score 6):

Floor function returns the greatest integer not greater than x. For example if the input is 2.25 then output will be 2.00. 
So in case of -0.1 greatest integer less than -0.1 would be -1.